# Four times the distance from the $x$-axis plus 9 times the distance from $y$-axis equals $10$.

Tags: geometry

What geometric figure is formed by the locus of points such that the sum of four times the distance from the $x$-axis and nine times its distance from $y$-axis is equal to $10$?

---

I get $4x+9y=10$. So it is a straight line, but the given answer is parallelogram. Can anyone tell me where my mistake is?

Comment: The distance of the point $(-1,-1)$ from the $x$-axis is $1$, not $-1$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If $P$ has coordinates $(x,y)$, then $d(P,x\text{ axis})=|y|$ and $d(P,y\text{ axis})=|x|$. So your stated condition requires $4|y|+9|x|=10$, the graph of which is shown below.

[image: Mathematica graphics]